# Access VBA to delete a file to the recycle bin?

Tags: vba, ms-access, filesystemobject

Using the following code delete's my file, but it doesn't go to the recycle bin - does code exist that will send it to the recycle bin?  Should I use ".Move" ?

```
If MsgBox("DELETE:" & Chr(10) & Forms("frmtbl").f_FullPath & Me.f_FileName & " ?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        'Kill Forms("frmtbl").f_FullPath & Me.f_FileName
        Dim objFSO As Object
        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        objFSO.DeleteFile (Forms("frmtbl").f_FullPath & Me.f_FileName)
        DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
Else
        MsgBox "FILE NOT DELETED:" & Chr(10) & Forms("frmtbl").f_FullPath & Me.f_FileName & ".", vbInformation, 
End If
```

.MoveFile to the recycle bin requires permissions I don't have.

Answer (score 4):

An integrated VBA-method seems not to exist. API call is needed.

Following code is copied from [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/41y4eo/excel_vba_delete_file_to_recycle_bin_modify/). (solution by "Crushnaut")

```
Option Explicit

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Windows API functions, constants,and types.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SHFileOperation Lib "shell32.dll" Alias _
    "SHFileOperationA" (lpFileOp As SHFILEOPSTRUCT) As LongPtr

Private Const FO_DELETE = &H3
Private Const FOF_ALLOWUNDO = &H40
Private Const FOF_NOCONFIRMATION = &H10

Private Type SHFILEOPSTRUCT
    hwnd As LongPtr
    wFunc As LongPtr
    pFrom As String
    pTo As String
    fFlags As Integer
    fAnyOperationsAborted As Boolean
    hNameMappings As LongPtr
    lpszProgressTitle As String
End Type

Public Function Recycle(FileSpec As String, Optional ErrText As String) As Boolean
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Recycle
' This function sends FileSpec to the Recycle Bin. There
' are no restriction on what can be recycled. FileSpec
' must be a fully qualified folder or file name on the
' local machine.
' The function returns True if successful or False if
' an error occurs. If an error occurs, the reason for the
' error is placed in the ErrText varaible.
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Dim SHFileOp As SHFILEOPSTRUCT
Dim Res As LongPtr
Dim sFileSpec As String

ErrText = vbNullString
sFileSpec = FileSpec

If InStr(1, FileSpec, ":", vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Not a fully qualified name. Get out.
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ErrText = "'" & FileSpec & "' is not a fully qualified name on the local machine"
    Recycle = False
    Exit Function
End If

If Dir(FileSpec, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
    ErrText = "'" & FileSpec & "' does not exist"
    Recycle = False
    Exit Function
End If

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Remove trailing '\' if required.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
If Right(sFileSpec, 1) = "\" Then
    sFileSpec = Left(sFileSpec, Len(sFileSpec) - 1)
End If


With SHFileOp
    .wFunc = FO_DELETE
    .pFrom = sFileSpec
    .fFlags = FOF_ALLOWUNDO
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' If you want to supress the
    ' "Are you sure?" message, use
    ' the following:
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    .fFlags = FOF_ALLOWUNDO + FOF_NOCONFIRMATION
End With

Res = SHFileOperation(SHFileOp)
If Res = 0 Then
    Recycle = True
Else
    Recycle = False
End If

End Function
```