# Can we Delete the word Document using VB macro present inside that document itself

Tags: vba, ms-word

i have a word document where i am doing some operation using Vb code. i want to delete the document once all the operations are completed using the Vb Code present inside that document itself avoiding the need of any external macro or any external application to delete the Document.

kill function is not working as document should be closed before deleting and once document is closed the code stops running there itself. is there any way we can do this from the given word file itself.

Sub DeleteCurrentDoc()

Dim deletepath As String

deletepath = ActiveDocument.FullName

ActiveDocument.Close False

Kill (deletepath)

Application.Quit

End Sub

Comment: Is writing a batch file to a system temp folder and doing the job from there an option?

Comment: yes it can be done that way. Can you show me how to do it

Comment: This might be useful -the code would work in Word as well as Access: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46357125/access-vba-to-delete-a-file-to-the-recycle-bin

Comment: Hi harassed, the code to delete the file to recycle bin works for the word document but only for the closed document. My problem is that I want to delete my document from the VB code present inside it. Which I am feeling is not possible as everytime the code will give error 70 permission denied. Can you help with this?